# Google App Script trigger is not firing

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a Google App Script user since last 2 years. I see here in India during peak time i.e during evening the 1 minute trigger is not firing at proper time. Is there any server side issue or there is some other issue. Saying about the worse case scenarios, today my script trigger has not been fired since past 2 hours. I have correctly done logging. No log is printed means it does not even go to that method. Can anybody tell me what might be the exact reason behind it.

Answer (score 1):

It might be beneficial to show us the code behind your script, given that there is a method that is potentially being skipped over. Have there been no errors thrown to you via the Google Apps Script notifications?

It seems, perhaps, your issue *may* fall into place with this currently reported error: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2708

We're likely not going to be able to give you a precise answer to your problem if we can't examine what you're currently working with. I wish you luck in your endeavor, though.